# Singleton design & new objects inside it

Tags: java, singleton

In a specific scenario here,

I have a manger called UserManger used to handle CRUD for user

This manager is "Singleton" and correct by design.

But in update method I have logic

```
public User update (User u) 
{

    // This line is problematic?
    User u1 = new User();

    copy(u,u1);
    //Some logic
    dao.update(u);

}
```

Will creating any new objects in singleton manager problematic? Especially for a very concurrent system.

Will

```
public User update (User u, User u1)
{

    copy(u,u1);
    //Some logic
    dao.update(u);
}
```

Solve my problem?

Comment: u & u1 are objects of User class. User class is simple dto which has getters & setters for User properties like name, age etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just creating an object within a singleton method won't cause any problems. You're not sharing any state between threads, after all.

You would have potential problems if you had state within the singleton itself - but all you've shown is creating a *local* variable, not changing an *instance* variable. Each invocation of a method has its own entirely separate set of local variables. Two threads can both be executing the same method, but they won't see each other's local variables.

Comment: Ok should this mean that if I change something like u1.setId(u.getId()); Or u1.generateXYZ(u.getID()); then it will be problematic ?

Comment: @Amol: No, because that's still not state within the singleton, is it?

Comment: @Jon But values of inside newly created objects are getting set using the parametrized object so I think it may be a issue to use such logic?

Comment: @Amol: Why? What *exactly* is your concern? If that object is shared between threads that could be a problem - but that has *nothing* to do with this being a singleton.

Comment: @Amol: agree with Skeet. It's not related with this one being singleton.

Comment: @Jon - Not exactly. My concern is that the internal state of this updated method must be thread safe. Actually there are many such objects created and used in this method. Typically one is an Hibernate criteria object which sets the criteria and this criteria is executed by DAO layer to return results. It must not happen that two or more threads adding or changing this criteria and creating mess.

Comment: @Amol: If you're creating a *new* criteria in the method, then it doesn't matter... because it'll still only be accessed by that thread. I still think you're getting confused about the implication of this being a singleton...

Comment: @Jon May be over conscious. Thanks anyways! A new thread needed? New thread required to know - What not to do in an singleton class methods. I will start it.

Answer (score 0):

No. But if you put

```
User u1;
```

as a global variable, It will cause issue.

But I have a question, why dont you code this way?

```
public User update (User u) 
{

    //Some logic
    User u = dao.update(u);
    return u;
    // OR return dao.update(u);
}
```

You don't need to copy here. Do a copy will need memory allocated 2 times more for User object in this method.

Comment: It's not called a *global variable* in Java. ;) *Field*, *attribute*, *property* (sans getter and setter method), or *class variable* is a more consistent name for it.

Comment: Yes. You are correct here in general case but here copy is part of business logic so can't avoid it. But does creating any objects and using them inside such update method cause any problem, when values of newly created object inside is affected by values of objects coming as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding your system, I have to call in to question the design patterns described here. Both [Singleton](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48811/what-design-patterns-are-the-worst-or-most-narrowly-defined) and [SomethingManager](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/03/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager.html) are anti-patterns.

You may just need to consider a more descriptive name for `UserManager`, but I would highly recommend using an [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) framework like [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) to inject it where it is required rather than nailing it down as a 'global' (which is essentially what a singleton is).

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that Singleton is anti-pattern. And do you know that the default scope for bean in Spring is singleton? :P

Comment: @Rudy Read the link to understand why it's an anti-pattern. There are several other pages that describe it nicely: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne **But** you also mistake singleton scope from Spring as the Singleton Pattern. They are very different in that the scope from Spring does not hard-code that scope in to the class.